# Hash + salt&pepper + Forward relationship

Tags: hash, salt

Well, This question is just for design proposes.

2 clients `ClientA`and `ClientB` users can access to their office using their IDcard. This IDCard is saved in a DB using salt&pepper to create a  user pseudonymization between the clients.

**ClientA DB**

```
Username    String to be Hashed             Hashed Value
ClientA     UserIDCard1+E1F53135E559C253    72ae25495a7981c4062...
ClientA     UserIDCard2+E1F53135E559C253    a52e4f1565c90f048f8...
ClientA     UserIDCard3+E1F53135E559C253    59027bd9c8c8900d5c3...
```

**ClientB DB**

```
Username    String to be Hashed             Hashed Value
ClientB     UserIDCard1+B7E459A02CB31F3C    b4b6603abc67096754...
ClientB     UserIDCard2+B7E459A02CB31F3C    e99c7e7f1389e40cd3...
ClientB     UserIDCard3+B7E459A02CB31F3C    16e78ad38eb1468edf...
```

That means if `UserIDCard1` visits `ClientA` and then `ClientB`,  the UserIDCard1 will be treated as a different user, which is good for pseudonymization (If an attacker gets access to DB) but bad if in the future Clients decide to merge ClientAB.

Is there a way to keep the pseudonymization across DBs but at the same time know if UserIDCard1 was in ClientA's building and ClientB's building? Or by definition Hash+Salt are **NOT** to be able to compare hashed values?

**edit**

The propose of these DBs is to get anonymous statistics about Client's users without compromising user's privacy across different DBs by storing their 'UserIDCard'.

Comment: That is not a salt, a salt as a new value per entry. A single value for the entire db is sometimes known as a "pepper" but it does not provide the protection a real Salt does.

Comment: a question about this design. Is there any reason the interface cannot broadcast its client ID? If so then you can store a client_id field in the DB table for these users. The salt can be unique per Card/Client pair which also makes this a bit stronger than reutilizing a single value per client across all its users.

Comment: @CorvusCrypto do you mean UserID? the reason I don't save UserID in the DB is because it can be attached to a person very easy and can become in a privacy issue. Also the propose of this DB is to get anonymous information like traffic or average time of checking in/out, stuff like that.

Comment: ah I see now. how fun :) gonna fave this and think about it a bit.